# How to find out sub-sites (like facebook.stackoverflow.com) of a SO site?

Tags: support, mini-site, subdomains

Somewhere I noticed reference to `facebook.stackoverflow.com`. I checked and found [this announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/).

I want to know if there are other sub-sites also, if they exist, how to find them?

I would be more interested in .NET specific sites. (Tags does that, but `dotnet.stackoverflow.com` sounds better).

Comment: No, there aren't any others. It was a failed experiment.

Comment: @Oded in what sense did it fail?

Comment: @djechlin - The idea was that it would become the go-to place for facebook programming questions. That has not happened, and in fact, we end up getting end-user support questions instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ is the only "filtered view" sub-site in the Stack Exchange network.  The only other sub-sites are the per-site Metas, but they have a separate pool of questions from the main site they serve.